# What is the setting that governs where your executables point to depending on the method of remote connection?

Tags: ssh

I don't know why this happens, but when I connect to a remote linux server through terminal & ssh or through visual studio code, it seems some of my executables are pointed to different versions.

For example, I have an executable called `analyze_sim`, which is a custom module that we put in a python installation. On visual studio code, when I do it points to `/opt/python3.7/bin/analyze_sim`. On terminal and after ssh'ing into the server, it points to `/opt/python2.7/bin/analyze_sim`.

What is the setting that governs where these executables point to depending on your method of connection?

Answer (score 1):

ssh invokes a shell, which keeps to the environment given to it, and then reads the contents of the shell initializaton scripts (e.g. ~/.bashrc). Your other connections might simply not do that.

Comment: I tried `source ~/.bashrc` for each connection and still have the same issue

Comment: you will have to check the actual PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHONPATH environment variables, as well as what visual studio explicitly enforces.